# Using poll() to manage read and write in a pipe use by multiple child process

Tags: c, pipe, epoll

I have a program in C that reads files (which are passed as arguments to main) containing bash commands, ex:

File 1 contains:

```
echo A
echo B
```

File 2 contains:

```
echo C
echo D
```

Through `fork`, the child process writes to a pipe the `stdout` of those commands executed with `execv`, and the parents reads it and prints it on the screen.

Now, there isn't any problem if there is only 1 file passed as argument, but here is the behavior I want if two files are passed as argument (the output that the program should print):

```
A
C
B
D
```

Instead of

```
A
B
C
D
```

I want the child to write to pipes and the parents to read the pipes in parallel. The first line of the first file is read and it's output is printed, then the first line of the second file is read and it's output is printed, then the second line of the first file is read and printed and it's output is printed, then the second line of the second file is read and it's output is printed, etc.

For this, I need to use the `poll()` function. I know this function can help monitor read and write from pipes, but I don't understand quite it's use and I don't get much from the man about it's use with pipes.

Is it possible to get a sample example of how to use poll to monitor the multiple child that would be forked if multiple files are passed as argument and the management of the pipe that would be used by multiple child and parents?

Comment: You don't need `poll()` for this. Just alternate between reading from the two pipes.

Comment: You would use `poll()` if you wanted to read from whichever pipe had data available, but that's exactly what you don't want.

Comment: So if I'm in a situation were it is imposed that I use ```poll()```, I must create multiple pipes and ```poll()``` would allow to read whenever a pipe has data available? Do you know a link or an example that would explain this?